# Extracting image from API

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script

Trying to output an image from an API but I keep getting an error "Empty JSON string"

```
function getIcon2(id)
{
  var api = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=";
  var data2 = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(api + id));
  return data2.item.icon_large;
}

function iconTest(){
  var icon = getIcon2(itemsheet.getRange("C2").getValue());
  itemsheet.getRange("D18").setValue(data2);
}
```

Comment: are you sure you are using a valid id?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
function getIcon() { 
  for(var i = 2; i < 500; i++) {
    id = itemsheet.getRange("C" + i).getValue()
    if(id == "")
      return; //If the cell is empty, ignore it.

    try {
      target = itemsheet.getRange("B" + i);
      var api = "http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/catalogue/detail.json?item=";
      var raw = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api + id);
      var data = JSON.parse(raw);
      formula = "=image(\"" + data.item.icon_large + "\",1)";
      target.setFormula(formula);
    } catch(err) {
      Logger.log("getIcon...." + err)
      return;
    }
  }
}
```